# 2003 Hummer H2 Ignition Lock Cylinder Has Hole Drilled into It from Car Thieves

Tags: ignition-key, hummer, h2

Alright so my vehicle was broken into and they drilled a hole into the ignition lock cylinder.  I am unable to turn the cylinder lock at all with my key. Putting a new ignition lock cylinder in seems to be a straight forward process but I have no idea how to get the old one out. I know there is a button/pin that you push down on top of the cylinder by using a bobby pin or something like it, but I think I need to put the cylinder in the on position for me to be able to slide it out. I try wiggling it by grabbing a jagged piece with needle nose pliers but it won't budge.

Here is a picture of it:
[image]

Any ideas on how to get it out?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 ways. drill the center hole bigger or drill the side bar out. Its around 7 o clock on your picture.This bar is what prevents the lock from turning. Once this is drilled away or pried out from drilling center bigger, then you can turn (and hold) whats left of the cylinder to the CRANK position with a large flat head. You will then need to push in the spring retainer pin. Once the retainer pin is being pushed in you can pull the cylinder out some, then you release from crank to "ON" and it will pull the rest of the way out without damaging the housing. (the retainer pin is where the tiny little hole is at the top)

[image]

Comment: Great information. +1 ... I bet this is applicable to more than just the H2 ... I'm hoping the housing isn't messed up, as that's what it looks like.

Comment: @Paulster2 it does look slightly damaged. I think it may be okay. What is that button/pin on the housing right by where the cylinder is?One of them has been sawed off

Comment: @WolfZwiener the piece missing is just a spring loaded pin, its meant to push the cylinder back out from where you need to push it in when turning "OFF".
You will be ok with just  1 but uou should remove the spring that is still in there so it doesn't come out later and cause a dragging feeling when turning key. The housing looks ok to me. A little scuffing on it is not a big deal .

Comment: @narkeleptk Okay thanks. Just to be clear I should take out the spring that has been sawed off?