# 2003 Hummer H2 Coding an Ignition Lock Cylinder

Tags: locks, ignition-key, hummer, h2

Recently I had to drill out my ignition lock cylinder out because someone broke into my vehicle and drilled a hole into it. See the question about that here: [2003 Hummer H2 Ignition Lock Cylinder Has Hole Drilled into It from Car Thieves](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/88046/2003-hummer-h2-ignition-lock-cylinder-has-hole-drilled-into-it-from-car-thieves)

I got a new ignition lock cylinder that's uncoded with the tumblers and springs that go with it and I'm trying to figure out how I would get the order right with my key. There are four different tumblers, numbered 1-4. Is there a way to know which tumblers go where from just looking at the key?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key has 4 depths and 10 spaces. 1 being the shallowest, 4 being the deepest and you can not have a 1 next to a 4.

Your ignition only uses spaces 1-9.

You can figure it out pretty easy by doing one wafer at a time. Put your key in the cylinder and then put in the wafer you think is the correct depth. Push the wafer all the way down to where it meets the key. Then Push in the side bar with your finger. If it goes in all the way flush with cylinder you picked the correct depth. If the side bar does not go in flush then you guessed wrong. Once you get all the positions correct then you put the springs in and then the spring cap.

If you give me the code off your old ignition cylinder (it will look like s###k) or if you send me a picture of your key, I can tell you what your code is. I suggest you do this through email or the contact page on my website. (just google Keyworks Richmond va)